# How to fix the deprecated issue of ffmpeg?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I try to compile the example code "transcoding" of ffmpeg. However, I encounter one deprecated issue of ffmpeg. After I added a inline=__inline and _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE to the preprocessor definition, the following error still exists. I don't know how to fix that. Please help.

The error shows that `error C4996: 'avcodec_encode_video2': was declared deprecated` for the line

int(*enc_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVPacket *, const AVFrame *, int *) =
                (ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type ==
                AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) ? avcodec_encode_video2 : avcodec_encode_audio2;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>

#pragma warning(disable 4996)

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define snprintf _snprintf
#endif

static AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx;
static AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx;
typedef struct FilteringContext {
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx;
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
} FilteringContext;
static FilteringContext *filter_ctx;

typedef struct StreamContext {
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx;
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx;
} StreamContext;
static StreamContext *stream_ctx;

static int open_input_file(const char *filename)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ifmt_ctx = NULL;
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
        return ret;
    }

    stream_ctx = (StreamContext *)av_mallocz_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*stream_ctx));
    if (!stream_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        AVCodec *dec = avcodec_find_decoder(stream->codecpar->codec_id);
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
        if (!dec) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to find decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR_DECODER_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
        if (!codec_ctx) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to allocate the decoder context for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        }
        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy decoder parameters to input decoder context "
                "for stream #%u\n", i);
            return ret;
        }
        /* Reencode video & audio and remux subtitles etc. */
        if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                codec_ctx->framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(ifmt_ctx, stream, NULL);
            /* Open decoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, dec, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
        }
        stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx = codec_ctx;
    }

    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, filename, 0);
    return 0;
}

static int open_output_file(const char *filename)
{
    AVStream *out_stream;
    AVStream *in_stream;
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx, *enc_ctx;
    AVCodec *encoder;
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not create output context\n");
        return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!out_stream) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        }

        in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        dec_ctx = stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx;

        if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            /* in this example, we choose transcoding to same codec */
            encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(dec_ctx->codec_id);
            if (!encoder) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Necessary encoder not found\n");
                return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
            }
            enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            if (!enc_ctx) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to allocate the encoder context\n");
                return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            }

            /* In this example, we transcode to same properties (picture size,
            * sample rate etc.). These properties can be changed for output
            * streams easily using filters */
            if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                enc_ctx->height = dec_ctx->height;
                enc_ctx->width = dec_ctx->width;
                enc_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio = dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio;
                /* take first format from list of supported formats */
                if (encoder->pix_fmts)
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = encoder->pix_fmts[0];
                else
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = dec_ctx->pix_fmt;
                /* video time_base can be set to whatever is handy and supported by encoder */
                enc_ctx->time_base = av_inv_q(dec_ctx->framerate);
            }
            else {
                enc_ctx->sample_rate = dec_ctx->sample_rate;
                enc_ctx->channel_layout = dec_ctx->channel_layout;
                enc_ctx->channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(enc_ctx->channel_layout);
                /* take first format from list of supported formats */
                enc_ctx->sample_fmt = encoder->sample_fmts[0];
                enc_ctx->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, enc_ctx->sample_rate };
            }

            /* Third parameter can be used to pass settings to encoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(enc_ctx, encoder, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video encoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, enc_ctx);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy encoder parameters to output stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                enc_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

            out_stream->time_base = enc_ctx->time_base;
            stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx = enc_ctx;
        }
        else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Elementary stream #%d is of unknown type, cannot proceed\n", i);
            return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
        }
        else {
            /* if this stream must be remuxed */
            ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, in_stream->codecpar);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Copying parameters for stream #%u failed\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            out_stream->time_base = in_stream->time_base;
        }

    }
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, filename, 1);

    if (!(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not open output file '%s'", filename);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    /* init muxer, write output file header */
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int init_filter(FilteringContext* fctx, AVCodecContext *dec_ctx,
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, const char *filter_spec)
{
    char args[512];
    int ret = 0;
    AVFilter *buffersrc = NULL;
    AVFilter *buffersink = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterInOut *outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut *inputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();

    if (!outputs || !inputs || !filter_graph) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }

        snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
            dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
            dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
            args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
            NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->pix_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->pix_fmt),
            AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output pixel format\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }
    else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }

        if (!dec_ctx->channel_layout)
            dec_ctx->channel_layout =
            av_get_default_channel_layout(dec_ctx->channels);
        snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "time_base=%d/%d:sample_rate=%d:sample_fmt=%s:channel_layout=0x%"PRIx64,
            dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den, dec_ctx->sample_rate,
            av_get_sample_fmt_name(dec_ctx->sample_fmt),
            dec_ctx->channel_layout);
        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
            args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create audio buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
            NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create audio buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "sample_fmts",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->sample_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->sample_fmt),
            AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output sample format\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "channel_layouts",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->channel_layout,
            sizeof(enc_ctx->channel_layout), AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output channel layout\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "sample_rates",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->sample_rate, sizeof(enc_ctx->sample_rate),
            AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output sample rate\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }
    else {
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }

    /* Endpoints for the filter graph. */
    outputs->name = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    outputs->pad_idx = 0;
    outputs->next = NULL;

    inputs->name = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    inputs->pad_idx = 0;
    inputs->next = NULL;

    if (!outputs->name || !inputs->name) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filter_spec,
        &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* Fill FilteringContext */
    fctx->buffersrc_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    fctx->buffersink_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    fctx->filter_graph = filter_graph;

end:
    avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
    avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);

    return ret;
}

static int init_filters(void)
{
    const char *filter_spec;
    unsigned int i;
    int ret;
    filter_ctx = (FilteringContext *)av_malloc_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*filter_ctx));
    if (!filter_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        filter_ctx[i].buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].buffersink_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].filter_graph = NULL;
        if (!(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
            || ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO))
            continue;


        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            filter_spec = "null"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for video */
        else
            filter_spec = "anull"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for audio */
        ret = init_filter(&filter_ctx[i], stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx,
            stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx, filter_spec);
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int encode_write_frame(AVFrame *filt_frame, unsigned int stream_index, int *got_frame) {
    int ret;
    int got_frame_local;
    AVPacket enc_pkt;
    int(*enc_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVPacket *, const AVFrame *, int *) =
        (ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type ==
        AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) ? avcodec_encode_video2 : avcodec_encode_audio2;

    if (!got_frame)
        got_frame = &got_frame_local;

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Encoding frame\n");
    /* encode filtered frame */
    enc_pkt.data = NULL;
    enc_pkt.size = 0;
    av_init_packet(&enc_pkt);
    ret = enc_func(stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx, &enc_pkt,
        filt_frame, got_frame);
    av_frame_free(&filt_frame);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;
    if (!(*got_frame))
        return 0;

    /* prepare packet for muxing */
    enc_pkt.stream_index = stream_index;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(&enc_pkt,
        stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->time_base,
        ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Muxing frame\n");
    /* mux encoded frame */
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt);
    return ret;
}

static int filter_encode_write_frame(AVFrame *frame, unsigned int stream_index)
{
    int ret;
    AVFrame *filt_frame;

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pushing decoded frame to filters\n");
    /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
    ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(filter_ctx[stream_index].buffersrc_ctx,
        frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
        return ret;
    }

    /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
    while (1) {
        filt_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!filt_frame) {
            ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            break;
        }
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pulling filtered frame from filters\n");
        ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(filter_ctx[stream_index].buffersink_ctx,
            filt_frame);
        if (ret < 0) {
            /* if no more frames for output - returns AVERROR(EAGAIN)
            * if flushed and no more frames for output - returns AVERROR_EOF
            * rewrite retcode to 0 to show it as normal procedure completion
            */
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                ret = 0;
            av_frame_free(&filt_frame);
            break;
        }

        filt_frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_NONE;
        ret = encode_write_frame(filt_frame, stream_index, NULL);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}

static int flush_encoder(unsigned int stream_index)
{
    int ret;
    int got_frame;

    if (!(stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->codec->capabilities &
        AV_CODEC_CAP_DELAY))
        return 0;

    while (1) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Flushing stream #%u encoder\n", stream_index);
        ret = encode_write_frame(NULL, stream_index, &got_frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
        if (!got_frame)
            return 0;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;
    AVPacket packet = { .data = NULL, .size = 0 };
    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    enum AVMediaType type;
    unsigned int stream_index;
    unsigned int i;
    int got_frame;
    int(*dec_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVFrame *, int *, const AVPacket *);

    if (argc != 3) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Usage: %s <input file> <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    av_register_all();
    avfilter_register_all();

    if ((ret = open_input_file(argv[1])) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = open_output_file(argv[2])) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = init_filters()) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* read all packets */
    while (1) {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &packet)) < 0)
            break;
        stream_index = packet.stream_index;
        type = ifmt_ctx->streams[packet.stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type;
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Demuxer gave frame of stream_index %u\n",
            stream_index);

        if (filter_ctx[stream_index].filter_graph) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Going to reencode&filter the frame\n");
            frame = av_frame_alloc();
            if (!frame) {
                ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
                break;
            }
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
                ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                stream_ctx[stream_index].dec_ctx->time_base);
            dec_func = (type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) ? avcodec_decode_video2 :
                avcodec_decode_audio4;
            ret = dec_func(stream_ctx[stream_index].dec_ctx, frame,
                &got_frame, &packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Decoding failed\n");
                break;
            }

            if (got_frame) {
                frame->pts = frame->best_effort_timestamp;
                ret = filter_encode_write_frame(frame, stream_index);
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                if (ret < 0)
                    goto end;
            }
            else {
                av_frame_free(&frame);
            }
        }
        else {
            /* remux this frame without reencoding */
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
                ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &packet);
            if (ret < 0)
                goto end;
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    /* flush filters and encoders */
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        /* flush filter */
        if (!filter_ctx[i].filter_graph)
            continue;
        ret = filter_encode_write_frame(NULL, i);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Flushing filter failed\n");
            goto end;
        }

        /* flush encoder */
        ret = flush_encoder(i);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Flushing encoder failed\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
    av_packet_unref(&packet);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx);
        if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > i && ofmt_ctx->streams[i] && stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx)
            avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx);
        if (filter_ctx && filter_ctx[i].filter_graph)
            avfilter_graph_free(&filter_ctx[i].filter_graph);
    }
    av_free(filter_ctx);
    av_free(stream_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

    if (ret < 0)
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));

    return ret ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: A side-by-side example of replacement can be found here: https://github.com/ferdymercury/amide/pull/23/files Also useful: https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=01000-97990449-e9f9-4b26-839a-b8c4cad60efa

Answer (score 2):

Best would be to find the replacement function for `avcodec_encode_video2` and use it instead of the deprecated one.

Unfortunately ffmpeg deprecation warnings do not give an idea what is the replacement, so you'll have to dig through ffmpeg release notes and documentation to find the actual replacement.

Answer (score 2):

From `avcodec.h` of the libavcodec library

> `avcodec_encode_video2()` is deprecated use `avcodec_send_frame()`/`avcodec_receive_packet()` instead

Comment: It's sad that most of the ffmpeg examples still use deprecated functions, though...

Answer (score 0):

We can check the FFMPEG's deprecated list from the official page. Choose your FFMPEG version and find the deprecated functions as well their respective replacements (if any)

sample links
[version 4.0](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/deprecated.html)
[version 3.4](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/deprecated.html)

Answer (score -3):

You can comment key word deprecated in file header ffmpeg lib

Comment: Why not just move `#pragma warning(disable 4996)` _before_ the includes?